# Does Delphi 11 IDE work in HTML or RichText mode?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

It would be very good if the programmer could write the code in `HTML` or `RichText` format so that, for example, a variable could have an `index in subscript format` or could `underline` a part of the code or use a `different color` in parts of the code, etc.

Does the Delphi IDE have this feature?

If so, can someone explain to me if and how the `HTML` option and `HTML formatting` do what I want?

Answer (score 6):

No, there certainly is no such support in RAD Studio (or any other mainstream IDE, I'd guess). A source-code file is a plain text file with no character formatting.

However, you can use most Unicode characters in identifiers, so, for example, you can do

```pascal
var α₁ := 5;
var α₂ := 7;
ShowMessage((α₁ + α₂).ToString);
```

This is not a feature of the IDE, but of the language (≈compiler).

But I would not be surprised if many people would object against the practice of using non-keyboard characters in the source code.

Comment: So, here's a (nice to me) idea for some newer version of Delphi. Support RichText format in IDE

Comment: This is a terrible idea

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. Why?

Comment: Can you come up with an outline specification of how this would work.

Comment: Currently, source files parsed by the compiler are plain text, to which the IDE adds a 'gloss' by colouring it and adding other details.  A rich text format would presumably have the source files in RTF format, and the parser would have to eliminate the formatting (involving extra difficulty and time) before processing the file.  Apart from that minor detail (ha!) it _would_ be a nice option for the user.

Answer (score 0):

3 Ideas on "improving" readability of your code, using IDE extensions or to make use of in-built Delphi features:

**More Color for your IDE (Since native Delphi IDE lacks source code highlighting imo)**

- What if you add a plugin like CNpack to your IDE? Here, for example, you can have your begin...end blocks (and much more) highlighted in color. It's more powerful than that, but you can also have only this feature active, while the others remain inactive. Many of my colleagues use only some of it.
- With 11.3 there's some improvements about [native-syntax highlighting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6bww1_nWrg) but i feel that other plugins still are more relieable.

**Custom variable names beside Unicode-Chars**

- You can also use character-escaping with the '&'-Char before your variable's name, eg:

  ```
  procedure WhyShouldIWantThat();
  var 
    &Then: TDateTime;
  begin
    &Then := Now;

    repeat

    // Something

    until MilliSeconds.Between(&Then, Now) > 1000;
  end;
  ```

Besides escaping, Delphi won't allow you to name a variable like a reserved name.

**Custom commentary above your Source Code**

- Make use of [XML Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/XML_Documentation_Comments).

Maybe you get some ideas.